# Break up async mocha test into multiple tests

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, mocha.js, solidity

To provide better test reporting, I am trying to break up some tests which contain a lot of steps to smaller steps. https://github.com/rocket-pool/rocketpool/blob/master/test/deposit/deposit-pool-tests.js

For example,

```
it(printTitle('staker', 'deposits 10 eth'), async () => {
        // Deposit
        await deposit({
            from: staker,
            value: '10'.ether,
        });

        // Get current rETH exchange rate
        let exchangeRate1 = await getRethExchangeRate();

        // Update network ETH total to 130% to alter rETH exchange rate
        let totalBalance = '13'.ether;
        let rethSupply = await getRethTotalSupply();
        await submitBalances(1, totalBalance, 0, rethSupply, {from: trustedNode});

        // Get & check updated rETH exchange rate
        let exchangeRate2 = await getRethExchangeRate();
        assertBN.notEqual(exchangeRate1, exchangeRate2, 'rETH exchange rate has not changed');

        // Deposit again with updated rETH exchange rate
        await deposit({
            from: staker,
            value: '10'.ether,
        });
    });
```

I would like to break this up into 5 `it` steps.

```
1. The staker deposits 10 ETH
2. The rETH exchange rate is retreived
3. The network ETH total is updated to 130% to alter rETH exchange rate
4. The rETH exchange rate is checked
5. The staker can deposit again with the updated rETH exchange rate
```

The problem is when I do this, the results of step 3 do not make it to step 4, and thus it fails. How can I properly use promises to accomplish this?
Here is what I am trying using mocha-cakes, getting an error that exchangeRate1 is equal to exchangeRate2

```
 Scenario('Staker can make a deposit before and after updating the rETH exchange rate',  () => { 
          let exchangeRate1;

            // Accounts
            const [
                owner,
                node,
                trustedNode,
                staker,
                random,
            ] = accounts;

                // Setup
            before(async () => {
                // Register node
                await registerNode({from: node});

                // Register trusted node
                await registerNode({from: trustedNode});
                await setNodeTrusted(trustedNode, 'saas_1', 'node@home.com', owner);
            });

            when('the staker deposits 10 ETH', async () => {
                await deposit({
                    from: staker,
                    value: '10'.ether,
                });
            });
    
            then('the staker should have successfully deposited 10 ETH', () => {
                // Add any additional checks you might need here
            });
    
            when('the rETH exchange rate is obtained', async () => {
                exchangeRate1 = await getRethExchangeRate();
            });
    
            then('the initial rETH exchange rate should be obtained', () => {
                // Add any additional checks you might need here
            });
    
            when('the network ETH total is updated to alter the rETH exchange rate', async () => {
                let totalBalance = '13'.ether;
                let rethSupply = await getRethTotalSupply();
                await submitBalances(1, totalBalance, 0, rethSupply, { from: trustedNode });
    
                // Delay to allow time for the update to take effect, if necessary
                await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
            });
    
            then('the rETH exchange rate should be updated', async () => {
                let exchangeRate2 = await getRethExchangeRate();
                assertBN.notEqual(exchangeRate1, exchangeRate2, 'rETH exchange rate has not changed');
            });
    
            when('the staker deposits 10 ETH again with the updated rETH exchange rate', async () => {
                await deposit({
                    from: staker,
                    value: '10'.ether,
                });
            });
    
            then('the staker should have successfully deposited 10 ETH again', () => {
                // Add any additional checks you might need here
            });
          });
    });
```

Comment: IMO, that's adding a lot of unnecessary noise... it's better in the original. `mocha-cakes` was abandoned 11 years ago, though. Someone made a follow up `mocha-cakes-2` that was abandoned 5 years ago. If I had to guess, the Gherkin style would only allow you to have 1 each of given->when->then.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below, since step 3 is working, collect the exchangeRate2 there( and declare exchangeRate2 earlier) then compare it in the next test.  You could also just combine that portion.

```
        let exchangeRate1;
         let exchangeRate2;

           // Accounts
           const [
               owner,
               node,
               trustedNode,
               staker,
               random,
           ] = accounts;

               // Setup
           before(async () => {
               // Register node
               await registerNode({from: node});

               // Register trusted node
               await registerNode({from: trustedNode});
               await setNodeTrusted(trustedNode, 'saas_1', 'node@home.com', owner);
           });

           when('the staker deposits 10 ETH', async () => {
               await deposit({
                   from: staker,
                   value: '10'.ether,
               });
           });
   
           then('the staker should have successfully deposited 10 ETH', () => {
               // Add any additional checks you might need here
           });
   
           when('the rETH exchange rate is obtained', async () => {
               exchangeRate1 = await getRethExchangeRate();
           });
   
           then('the initial rETH exchange rate should be obtained', () => {
               // Add any additional checks you might need here
           });
   
           when('the network ETH total is updated to alter the rETH exchange rate', async () => {
               let totalBalance = '13'.ether;
               let rethSupply = await getRethTotalSupply();
               await submitBalances(1, totalBalance, 0, rethSupply, { from: trustedNode });
   
               // Delay to allow time for the update to take effect, if necessary
               await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
               exchangeRate2 = await getRethExchangeRate();

           });
   
           then('the rETH exchange rate should be updated', async () => {
              
               assertBN.notEqual(exchangeRate1, exchangeRate2, 'rETH exchange rate has not changed');
           });
```

Overall though, the issue could be a bug in Mocha-cakes.  Mocha-cakes-2 was abandoned and lost support 5ish years ago so there could be any number of issues causing what your seeing.  You may want to look into frameworks or setup with more support that havent been abandoned